# How can I extract dll from GAC and view the codes in dll?

Tags: class, dll, gac, reflector

My VPC crashed and I lost 1 of my project's solutions,

the only latest copy is in the Global Assembly Cached(GAC) which I deployed.

Can anyone show me how to extract the dll from GAC by cmd prompt?

and how do I open the dll to view the code? if not mistaken can use a software called Reflector.

Please help.

Thank in advanced.

Comment: I have solved this by copy out the dll from GAC by cmd prompt, then use .net Reflector to extract the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad you managed to sort it out but I'd suggest that loading the assembly directly from the GAC from within Reflector is the easiest solution. You can do this via File > Open Global Assembly Cache.

Once you've loaded the assembly you can go ahead and export the code.

Comment: Don't have that option in .NET Reflector 6.8.2.5